# Обучение Python

Tags: python

Хотел бы обратиться за советом по обучению Python. Обладаю знаниями очень поверхностными, сталкивался только при написании тестов на selenium. Сейчас встал вопрос обучения. Вы не могли бы подсказать ресурс, или курсы, куда можно было бы пойти? советовали мне курсы от известной компании гикбрейнс, но о них ужасные отзывы везде. Проживаю в СПб, но думаю, что сейчас чаще встречается онлайн. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Я проходил пару курсов питона на https://stepik.org/ . Бесплатно. Неплохо там. Даже сертификаты генерируют после

Comment: "Изучаем Python" Марк Лутц
а вообще изучение без практики - фигня полная. Прочитав эту книжку я знал меньше чем потом написав мелкий скрипт. Устраивайтесь стажером за бесплатно, это the best way

Comment: Возможно, был невнимателен при написании. Не увидел этот вопрос. Спасибо за ваш ответ!

Comment: Для новичков поможет обзорная статья про профессию: https://professii.su/programmirovanie/python-razrabotchik.html. Там написано не только про то, чем занимается программист, но и содержатся много полезных ссылок на обучающие материалы.

Answer (score 0):

Я, обладая нулевыми знаниями, прошёл курс по python на stepik "Программирование на Python". Там также есть вторая часть. Гикбрейнс я не советую т.к цена, по моему мнению, не оправдана + большинство их курсов есть в свободном доступе.

[Ссылка на сайт](https://stepik.org)

[Ссылка на курс](https://stepik.org/course/67/syllabus)